# JavaScript Recursion Doesn't Resume

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is my script running on Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) (Windows 10 x64)

```
<script>  
var givenArray = [23, 6, [2, [6, 2, 1, 2], 2], 5, 2];
var printArray = function (start, array) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            printArray(start + 1, array[i]);
        }
        else {
            for (j = 0; j < start; j++) {
                document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            }
            document.write(array[i] + '<br/>');
        }
    }
};
printArray(0, givenArray);
</script>
```

This script should print

```
23
6
    2
        6
        2
        1
        2
    2
5
2
```

But it is printing only

```
23
6
    2
        6
        2
        1
        2
```

I mean, after the recursive call outer for loop ends or function returns.

What is the problem with this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/815386
https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using gloabal `i` and `j` that are shared by all the `printArray` calls. Use `var` to make `i` and `j` local:

```
var printArray = function (start, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
//       ^^^^ here
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            printArray(start + 1, array[i]);
        }
        else {
            for (var j = 0; j < start; j++) {
//               ^^^^ and here
                document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            }
            document.write(array[i] + '<br/>');
        }
    }
};
```

Never use variables without declaration, unless you want them to be globals.